# Why doesn't CMake put the `-L` flag in appropriate places?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I'm trying to build a shared library with cmake on linux. The portion of code responsible for setting this up is:

```
if (BUILD_SHARED)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)
    set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)
    # shared library
    add_library(semsim SHARED "${SEMSIM_HEADERS}" "${SEMSIM_SOURCES}")
    #Note: not sure if this command does anything. It was supposed to be to link static libraries into my shared one
#    target_link_options(semsim PUBLIC -Wl,--whole-archive)
#
    message(STATUS "LIBBZ_INCLUDE_DIR ${LIBBZ_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    target_include_directories(semsim PUBLIC # make public so include dirs propagate into test binaries
            ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            ${LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${LIBSBML_DEPS_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${LIBSBML_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${ZIPPER_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${LIBCOMBINE_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${BZ2_INCLUDE_DIR}

            ${REDLAND_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${RASQAL_INCLUDE_DIR}
            ${RAPTOR2_INCLUDE_DIR}

            )

    target_link_libraries(semsim PUBLIC # make public so libraries propagate into test binaries
            ${LIBCOMBINE_STATIC_LIBRARY}
            ${ZIPPER_STATIC_LIBRARY}
            ${ZLIB_STATIC_LIBRARY}
            ${LIBSBML_STATIC_LIB}
            ${LIBBZ_STATIC_LIBRARY}
            ${REDLAND_LIBRARY}
            ${RASQAL_LIBRARY}
            ${RAPTOR2_LIBRARY}
            ${LIBXML2_STATIC_LIBRARY}
            dl
            ${BZ2_STATIC_LIBRARY}
            curl xslt
            )

endif ()
```

This produces the following command for execution:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -std=c++14 -g  -shared -Wl,-soname,libsemsim.so -o libsemsim.so CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/CurlGet.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/RDFNode.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Subject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Predicate.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Resource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Triple.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/SemsimUtils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/MetaID.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/XmlAssistant.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Reader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Editor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Writer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/RDF.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Participant.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalEntity.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalPhenomenon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalProcess.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalPropertyResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalForce.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Query.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/SemsimCombineArchive.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Triples.cpp.o ../../third_party/libCombine-0.2.3/INSTALL/lib/libCombine-static.a ../../third_party/zipper/INSTALL/lib/libZipper-static.a ../../third_party/zlib-1.2.11/INSTALL/lib/libz.a /usr/local/lib/libxml2.a -ldl ../../third_party/libsbml-dependencies/INSTALL/lib/libbz2.a -lcurl -lxslt
```

If I let CMake try to build with this command I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.a(uri.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `xmlFree' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
```

However, I've noticed that the command produced by CMake is lacking `-L` flags. So I changed the command to :

```
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -std=c++14 -g -shared -o libsemsim.so CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/CurlGet.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/RDFNode.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Subject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Predicate.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Resource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Triple.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/SemsimUtils.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/MetaID.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/XmlAssistant.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Reader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Editor.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Writer.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/RDF.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Participant.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalEntity.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalPhenomenon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalProcess.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalPropertyResource.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/PhysicalForce.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Query.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/SemsimCombineArchive.cpp.o CMakeFiles/semsim.dir/Triples.cpp.o -L ../../third_party/libCombine-0.2.3/INSTALL/lib/libCombine-static.a -L ../../third_party/
zipper/INSTALL/lib/libZipper-static.a -L ../../third_party/zlib-1.2.11/INSTALL/lib/libz.a -L /usr/local/lib/libxml2.a -l
dl -L ../../third_party/libsbml-dependencies/INSTALL/lib/libbz2.a -lcurl -lxslt
```

ran it in a shell and it worked. Could anybody suggest why CMake is not using the `-L` flag in the appropriate places?

Comment: You are adding paths/strings to your library dependencies, if possible you should link against targets. That way all the dependencies, paths and settings for that target should be set up. So instead of `${LIBXML2_STATIC_LIBRARY}` you should link against just `libxml2`

Comment: Eh? Option `-L` (upper `l`) specifies a **directory** for search libraries. Linking with a library, specified by absolute (or relative) path doesn't require this option. Using `-L ../../third_party/libCombine-0.2.3/INSTALL/lib/libCombine-static.a` does NOT link with the library.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for pointing that out. Clearly I'm new at this - perhaps that is why I wasn't getting errors, they were not being used as intended!

Comment: @PeterT thanks for the suggestion, I'll try linking directly with `libxml2` (though still need to work out how CMake will know where it is).

Comment: @PeterT It worked! Passing `xml2` directly into `target_link_libraries` resolves the linker error. However, does this use static `libxml2` or the shared version?